# Loading resource fails at server-side

Tags: java, spring, resources, spring-boot, classloader

I have a library that load the resources in the following way:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(String.format("%s.txt", filename)), "UTF8")
);
```

Library's tests run fine.

After that another webapp (spring-boot) uses that library as a dependency (with Maven). But! If I run that webapp from Intellij - works fine. But when I upload it to server, or run it locally with `java -jar` it fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you use maven? or what is your building tool? It is a classpath problem, in IDE, IDE has own classpath and will see your jar but when you deply the app to server if it is not your webapp classpath it will throw exceptions. Try to build your web app at command prompt. You will see the same problem at your local.

Comment: Please use mvn clean install in command prompt and check is it working or throw exception.

Comment: Yes, as I said locally run with java -jar also fails.. the question is how to fix it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this depends on which ClassLoader is used.
I would suggest you define `classLoader` as

```
ClassLoader classLoader = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader();
```

where `SomeClass` is a class in the same jar that contains the '.txt' resources.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your class loader.If your class loader is not able to locate the resource it will return null.Try to load some resource which exist on your application's classpath. eg "myfolder/myfile.txt" where myfolder exist in root of your classpath.

See
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)